# getValue suddenly VERY SLOW this morning (fast last night)

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know about optimizing scripts to use getValues over a range in order to reduce the number of calls.
I've tremendously sped up the overall script by calling and creating an object that has all named ranges for the sheet as global object....very fast and 4x increase in over operation of all functions that get/set ranges.

I went to sleep last night with every running well. I woke up this morning to this:

```
[20-02-22 07:39:55:825 MST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([FALSE]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-22 07:39:55:825 MST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([TRUE]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-22 07:39:55:826 MST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[20-02-22 07:39:55:826 MST] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Status]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-22 07:39:55:827 MST] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([17:17]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-22 07:40:16:209 MST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [20.381 seconds]
[20-02-22 07:40:26:373 MST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [10.164 seconds]
[20-02-22 07:40:26:373 MST] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Sender]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-22 07:40:26:374 MST] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.activate() [0 seconds]
[20-02-22 07:40:26:374 MST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getColumn() [0 seconds]
[20-02-22 07:40:26:375 MST] Logger.log([Settings:Replies,,Complete, []]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-22 07:40:26:375 MST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue([NU6COI7]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-22 07:40:46:818 MST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues() [20.442 seconds]
```

Set values are very fast, but each and every get (even if just a single cell), it taking forever and then some. Ideas?  Is this Google having a bad morning or a script change that is odd?

I know big forumlas involved in the cells being called can slow down the get as Google waits for the results of formulas, but I don't have that.  There isn't a circular dependency or anything like that.  Internet is consistent.

---

---

ing like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It was Google.  I decided to just watch some videos and ignore this for a while.  An hour later, without touching it, all is back to normal.  Tested on different computers and all was the same having slow speeds.  Now fast as can be.  Internet speed still the same.